# Clean install of MacOS requires Remote Management

Tags: macos, ventura

In 2019 I was given a macbook pro from my employer and have been using it since then. When I left the company about 6 months ago they let me keep the laptop and I have had no issues until today when I tried to do a clean install of MacOS and am now required to sign in with "remote management" in order to complete the setup

I am wondering what is the best way to handle this situation. From my limited research it seems like there is absolutely no way to get around this without contacting the company directly, while I don't mind contacting my former employers I would prefer not to if that's possible. If I do contact them I am wondering if removing this is something they can do entirely remotely as I now live several thousand miles away from their office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact them. The whole point of that software is to control and limit access to the device.

Similar posts are on here and all afaik have not found a way to get round the software. Some had success with replacing the hard disk but that also depends on which machine.

This q+a may clarify the position for you:
[Remote Management and Verizon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396267/237687)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is simalar to this:
[Why do I get a ‘Remote Management’ step when installing High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311052/why-do-i-get-a-remote-management-step-when-installing-high-sierra)

temporary solution: install macos on external drive and boot from there

you probably need to contact the company. you might not need to go there if you use tools like ssh and apple's free screen sharing app. You can allow these through Preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing/Remote Login

you could call somebody at the company and ask them if they can disable it. you might not even need ssh/screen sharing. https://documentation.n-able.com/remote-management/userguide/Content/remove_mdm_enroll_profile_using_rmm.htm