# Can’t get rid of remote management, even after reinstalling OS

Tags: mobile-device-management

I have an old Macbook Pro that was previously managed by Mosyle. I’ve tried to remove it by 1) Erase Content & Settings and 2) reinstalling the OS however upon the first start up after the reinstall, I’m greeted by a Remote Management configuration window. How can I fully remove this software?

It’s worth noting that I cannot access anything outside of the first few initial set up screens.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a ‘Remote Management’ step when installing macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311052/why-do-i-get-a-remote-management-step-when-installing-macos)

Comment: You need to contact the original owners to get them to release it.